# Should I use a class to share multiple variables between functions?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, variables, global-variables

I have one big function that makes a number of measurements. A list of parameters is read from a database and files at the beginning of the function. Some of these parameters belong somewhat together (such as movement limits), others are separate. I'd prefer not to put all parameters in one dictionary, even just for the challenge of it.

To make the function more compact and less cluttered, I'd put the queries for all parameters in a separate function. However, I don't know the best/correct way to return multiple variables.

When searching my books and Stack Overflow, I find the following options:

1. I could return one dict with all variables, but wonder if there's another way.
2. Global variables: since I don't use the parameters elsewhere, this seems bad practice.
3. Return a tuple of variables, but then they'd not be named.
4. Most answers I found on Stack Overflow recommend creating a class. This would turn my function into a class.

So I am wondering, is this considered good practice: creating a class (with just two functions) for something that could be done in one single function?

Comment: In the context of option 3: have you ever tried [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an answer to such a question always depends on complexity.

But when you say:

> I have one big function that makes a number of measurements.

it could be an indication to think about restructuring.

i always prefer to let one function just do one simple thing.
[Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) teachs us "Simple is better than complex" and "Complex is better than complicated".

In that case i'd use a class instead of a function that is too complicated.

As a rule of thumb: if your function or method exceeds 20 Lines of Code or returns more than two or three parameters you should think about restructuring.
In most cases you want the function to be a "Jack of all trades". From time to time these functions blow up and handling them gets more and more complicated.

Comment: It is this restructuring that I am trying to do, making the code "cleaner" while better learning how to code. The function is one measurement cycle with lots of steps that sometimes depend on each other. I'm sure that it could be improved a lot, and maybe a class is the best solution to group all variables and functions....

Comment: Often you can divide a complex function in smaller parts, even if it is just one measurement cycle. When you show your code, it's eassier to identify improvements.  Variables that are used more than once are good candidates for class variables.

Answer (score 1):

Return a tuple; in your calling function you can use implicit tuple unpacking

```
top_limit, bottom_limit, another_value = the_query_function()
```

And inside the called function just:

```
return top_limit, bottom_limit, another_value
```

Pretty clean and easy, no boilerplate

Or you could use a class like you said, really depends on the complexity of the job at hand

EDIT: using a job for a call once task imo isn't bad style if the code profits from using a class

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using nested `dict`s to group parameters by some criteria.

For example:

```
d = {
    'movement_limits': {
        'top': 5,
        'bottom': 1,
    },
    'window_size': {
        'height': 10,
        'width': 10,
    },
    'num_players': 9,
}
```

And access it like this:

```
print(d['window_size']['height'])
print(d['movement_limits']['top'])
```

This has little overhead (not an entire class) and is still somewhat readable.